# Ios How to a add a button to my TabBarController then trigger the presentation of a modal view from it

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, ibaction, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a UITabBarController bassed app. I'm instantiating it from the app delegate and adding a custom button in the tab bar controller. when that button is clicked, I want to present another view modally, but I cant seem to figure out how to do it.  to add the button I'm basically doing this

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:button];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showModalViewController:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and also in the app delegate I have a method

```
- (void) showModalViewController {
    DummyViewController *addController = [[DummyViewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:@"DummyViewController" bundle:nil];
    //addController.delegate = self;

    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];


    // Create the navigation controller and present it modally.
    [self.tabBarController.selectedViewController presentModalViewController:addController animated:YES];

    // The navigation controller is now owned by the current view controller
}
```

I keep getting unrecognized seletor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector looks for a method named `showModalViewController:` but your actual method is named `showModalViewController`. Change one or the other.

Either change the selector to `@selector(showModalViewController)` to match the existing method, or change the method to:

```
- (void)showModalViewController:(UIButton *)button {
```

Don't change both.

Comment: Can you even add a button to the tab bar controller's view?

Comment: @rdelmar Apparently since he is. :)

Comment: I tried it -- you can, but it shows on top of the views of all the contained controllers. This is not a good design.

Comment: @rdelmar That's a separate question for the OP to deal with. This one is all about getting the button's action working.

Comment: I'm implementing a custom button for the center (This is something I have seen quite often) Since the button is larger than the tab bar, there is really no other way to make it work

Comment: @rmaddy after reading through this like 5 times, my eye finally caught the trailing : in the method name .... it's little thing like this that kill me